# WCF callback won't pass derived class

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-callbacks

### CLIENT SIDE

my client got the following callback contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IEvent
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnEvent(string serverName, string changeType, List<myObject> myObjects);

}
```

and got a class implementing **IEvent** as following:

```
class myClass : IEvent{
 public void OnEvent(string serverName, string changeType, List<myObject> myObjects)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Event Called: " + changeType + @" occured at: " + serverName     + @" got " + myObjects.Count + " myObjects!");
    }
}
```

### SERVER SIDE

my server got the following publishing code:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(client, new object[] {serverName, changeType, myObjects});
```

### The problem

When I use methodInfo.Invoke with `myObjects = new List<myobject>(){}`
all works fine meaning myClass.OnEvent is called when server uses methodinfo.invoke
and mbox is displayed

**BUT**

when I try to send `myObjects = new List<myobject>(){new MyDerivedObject()}` it doesn't work meaning myClass.OnEvent is **NOT** called when server uses methodinfo.invoke
and mbox is **NOT** displayed

both server and client contain references to myObject DLL that has both myObject and MyDerivedObject
MyDerivedObject is of course derived from myObject

**Help please**

Comment: Does the client have access to and load the library containing `MyDerivedObject`?

Comment: @Hand-E-Food
yes there is. both server and client contain references to myObject DLL that has both myObject and MyDerivedObject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example that @eugene gave can also be applied to a service contract, so in your case you could apply the ServiceKnownType to the callback contract.

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyDerivedObject))]
interface IEvent
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnEvent(string serverName, string changeType, List<myObject> myObjects);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To WCF be able using derived classes, the base class should be decorated with a `KnownType` attribute for each of derived classes. Unfortunately, this means that base class should know about its derived classes. In your case it will be like:

```
[KnownType(typeof(MyDerivedObject))]
[DataContract]
class myobject
{
     // ...
}
```

Comment: what can I do in case myObject is in a closed DLL I cannot touch?

Comment: You can try to create a wrapper object that holds the `myObject`, and define your list containing this wrapper. Additionally, you should add `ServiceKnownType` attribute to `OnEvent` method for each type:
`
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(myObject))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyDerivedObject))]
    [OperationContract]
    void OnEvent()
`